# Recover uncommitted changes after a mistaken merge

Tags: git, github

I was working in a branch (SRC) and had a bunch of uncommitted changes I was going to move over to another branch (DEST). I was in SRC and did "git merge DEST." Forgot to commit my changes before. It would appear as if days of work are lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any way to recover my changes?

Comment: Welcome to SO - this is a good question that would get more attention with a more specific descriptive title, such as *Recover uncommitted changes after a mistaken merge*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can undo the changes of just the merge by doing

```
git reset --merge
```

Comment: Will the uncommitted changes remain intact after reset?

Comment: That didn't appear to do anything. My files have not reappeared.

Comment: @Bhaskar yes, changes that were present before the merge, that is the idea.

Comment: @Sc0rpio did you commit after the merge?

Comment: @Sc0rpio Modified files were erased by the merge? That should not normally happen. You should have gotten `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge`

Comment: The files were definitely erased. After resetting the merge, they still did not appear. I did a stash and then applied it. I just checked and the files are back. No idea whether the merge or applying of the stash fixed the problem, but my files are back!

Comment: @Sc0rpio what do you mean exactly by "I did a stash and then applied it" can you please post your command? I have the same problem you had. Thank you.